# What Choice Axiom allows you to choose from a set-sized collection of Classes?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The standard axiom of choice states that every set of non-empty sets has a choice function.  And the axiom of global choice states that every *class* of non-empty sets has a choice function.  But I’m wondering how strong a choice axiom is required to get a choice function for a set-sized collection of classes.  Let me explain.

Let $X$ be a set, and let $\phi(x,y)$ be a formula such that for all $x\in X$, there exists a set $y$ such that $\phi(x,y)$.  Then my question is, what is required to prove that there exists a set $Y$ and a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that  $\phi(x,f(x))$ for all $x\in X$?

Is the standard axiom of choice sufficient to prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the standard axiom of choice is sufficient: intuitively, just replace each class $C$ with the set $V_{\alpha_C}\cap C$, where $\alpha_C$ is the smallest ordinal such that that set is nonempty. (This is the same idea behind [**Scott's trick**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick), although the latter refers more specifically to the "paring down" of equivalence classes.)

We could also phrase this in terms of shifting attention from the original formula $\varphi(x,y)$ to the formula $$\psi(x,y)\equiv\varphi(x,y)\wedge\forall z(rk(z)<rk(y)\implies\neg\varphi(x,z)),$$ where "$rk(a)$" is the rank of $a$ (that is, the smallest ordinal $\theta$ such that $a\in V_\theta$).